# UML representation of type being passed as a parameter

Tags: uml, methods, parameters

I want to draw a UML diagram of my program. Class `Barney` has a method `Yabadaba(Doo d)` which takes a parameter of type `Doo`.

How do I represent that class `Doo` is used in class `Barney` in my UML diagram?

Comment: What type of UML-diagram are you creating? Sequence, class, state, activity, ...?

Comment: @Kenneth class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smells like a homework. Oh well.

> I want to draw a UML diagram of my program.

What type of UML diagram? Class, sequence, collaboration? You need to learn to be precise and clear when asking questions.

With that said, I am going to assume you meant to ask for a class diagram (and my answer will be based off that assumption.)

> Class Barney has a method Yabadaba(Doo d) which takes a parameter of
>   type Doo.
>
> How do I represent that class Doo is used in class Barney in my UML
>   diagram?

You represent it by having a class artifact for Barney, in a class diagram, and with a method that takes the type  (Doo) in question

[image]

If, the class Barney has a member field of type Doo, in addition to a method that takes an instance of Doo, then, you will have Barney with a Doo field on it.

[image]

Either that, or as an aggregation/association of some type. This example would show a composition of Barney with Doo.

[image]

What association/method you use to represent this, that depends on what you want to do. And for that, well, the solution is to read the manual. Hope it helps.

=== edit ===

btw, these images were created with the [yuml.me](http://yuml.me) online drawing tool.

Comment: It's not homework at all, but Thanks!!

Comment: I believe it is required to supply a parameter name, not just a type (in UML 2.5).

Answer (score 7):

At the very least, you want a [dependency relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28UML%29) from class `Barney` to class `Doo`:

[image: Dependency]

If class `Barney` maintains an instance of `Doo` at some point in its life, then the relationship is stronger and becomes an [association relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_%28object-oriented_programming%29):

[image: Association]

The association relationship can be made even strong by adding a direction.

You can also consider multiplicity, which is the number of elements. This is most useful for if the element is optional or for composition/aggregation relationships. You may also decide that it may not be appropriate to include the `Doo` class in your model, in which case you can simply indicate the method exists in `Barney`.

Answer (score -3):

The Class Barney have not any relationship, but next class Barney you put enumeration class Doo with the Doo property.

Comment: Huh?  Could you explain that with a picture or diagram? You may find http://asciiflow.com useful for creating an ascii-art diagram for this.